# How to Skip a Webpage After a Period of Time Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am parsing a file with a ton of colleges. Selenium googles `"Admissions " + college_name` then clicks the first link and gets some data from each page. The issue is that the list of college names I am pulling from is very rough (technically a list of all accredited institutions in America), so some of the links are broken or get stuck in a load loop. How do I set some sort of timer that basically says

```
    if page load time > x seconds:
        go to next element in list
```

Comment: The default timeout for pageload can be pretty large depending on the driver.  You can set that ( https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit- ), and/or use "PageLoadStrategy" settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invoke `WebDriverWait` on the page, and if the page catches a `TimeoutException` then you will know it took too long to load, so you can proceed to the next one.

Given you do not know what each page HTML will look like, this is a very challenging problem.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# list of college names
names = []

for name in names:
    # search for the college here

    # get list of search results
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rc']")))
    search_results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rc']")

    # get first result
    search_result = search_results[0]

    # attempt to load the page
    try:
        search_result.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        # click operation should time out if next page does not load
        # pass to move on to next URL
        pass
```

This is a very rough, general outline. As I mentioned, without knowing what the expected page title will be, or what the expected page content will look like, it's incredibly difficult to write a generic method that will successfully accomplish this. This code is meant to be just a starting point for you.